# jQuery find a class and create callback for its last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In 'jQuery' I can execute callback for all elements of a class like this way -

```
jQuery(form_id).find(".multiple_upldprev").each(function () {
```

But I want to execute only last element of the class. I tried this way -

```
jQuery(form_id).find(".multiple_upldprev").last(function () {
```

It doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: What callback? Event?

Comment: Use `last()` or `.find(".multiple_upldprev:last")`. However you can't just apply a function to the element, you need to run it under a event handler.

Comment: Actually when each function exucutes then there is a for loop. But I want to execute only last index for `multiple_upldprev` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last()` will reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set. And it does *not* take a handler. You can use:

```
$(...).last().each(function() {

});
```

Which usually doesn't make sense since `.last()` just returns the element:

```
var $lastElement = $(...).last();
// Do something with $lastElement
```

In cases where you have a predefined handler each might make sense:

```
$(...).last().each(myHandler);
// The same can roughly be archived with:
myHandler.call($(...).get(-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont event need a callback.

Since you are interested only in executing a function on last element, You can just do this with a **self executing function** and the **last element in a variable**.

```
(function(){
  var $last = jQuery(form_id).find(".multiple_upldprev").last();
  // now use this $last 
})();
```

---

Or for some reason you want to use callback by using each but still execute the callback function only for the last element then you can do this with the help of **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**..

```
jQuery(form_id).find(".multiple_upldprev").each(function () { 
  var isLastElement = $(this).is(".multiple_upldprev:last"); //return true only for last element in loop
  if(isLastElement ){
   //execute your logic for last element
  }
});
```